# Url.Action com routevalues e objetos

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, razor

Tenho a seguinte [Url.Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "AreaName" })
```

Preciso enviar também alguns objetos para essa `action` através dessa `Url.Action`, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deu certo enviando com o router, ficou assim:

```
@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "AreaName", parametroName = "parametroValue" })
```